# Quasar: Remove header in dialog menu in q-select

Tags: vue.js, dialog, vue-component, quasar-framework, quasar

I am customizing this dialog menu from the dialog behavior of q-select in quasar. but i cant figure out a way to remove this:

[image: dialog]

any idea how i should go about this? is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind guys I figured it out. I used `.q-select__dialog label{ display: none }` and it worked :D

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write extra CSS to just remove the label. You can just remove the label property and it will work.

```
<q-select color="purple-12" v-model="model" :options="options">
    <template v-slot:prepend>
      <q-icon name="event" />
    </template>
 </q-select>
```

**label** : String

Description
**A text label that will “float” up above the input field, once the field gets focus**